# Unable to see .NET Users in IIS in .NET 4

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, iis, asp.net-membership

I have converted my web from 3.5 to 4.0 and now in the IIS - my membership management is gone (.NET USERS), where can I Manage them?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Login fails after upgrade to ASP.net 4.0 from 3.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739196/login-fails-after-upgrade-to-asp-net-4-0-from-3-5). Short answer: the hashing algorithm has changed in 4.0, you need to put `<machineKey validation="SHA1" />` in your `web.config` file to use the older algorithm.

Comment: I dont have problems logging in. I have problems managing them, since the .NET users icon is missing in the IIS

Comment: @oshafran, I see a `.NET Users` icon in the main pane of the IIS7 manager when I select the `Default Web Site`. Where are you looking for it?

Comment: I have another WebSite in the IIS with 4.0 application pool and its showing only on websites with 2.0

Comment: @oshafran, but neither you nor your users have any problem logging into that site?

Comment: Sounds like a ServerFault issue since there is no code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It might be same problem as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939852/how-to-add-users-in-iis-manager-for-an-asp-net-4-0-application). Basically IIS does not (yet) support management of users and roles if you set the application pool to .NET 4. You have to switch to a .NET 2.0 application pool and disable the targetframework 4.0 attribute in your web.config to manage users. After you are done with user management in IIS you can return to 4.0 pool and target framework settings.