# .NET Users missing IIS 10.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication, iis-10

I have an asp.net web application (.Net Framework 3.5 based) which uses Forms Authentication (AspNetSqlMembershipProvider). I managed my users in localhost but when I deployed my application to server, I cannot manage users, because in iis manager screen, .NET Users icon is missing. My site's application pool .NetCLR version is 2.0

I want to know how to manage my users. Appreciate for help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add users in IIS Manager for an ASP.NET 4.0 application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939852/how-to-add-users-in-iis-manager-for-an-asp-net-4-0-application)

Comment: Have you tried to set app pool to 4.0 and view the .net user. Then change app pool to 2.0 with refresh the site list.